# servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter in scout Mars

Tags: eclipse-scout

in my scout project with version Mars 5.0 I implemented a login with the use of DataSourceSecurityFilter but when launch the RAP client on the browser return an error "HttpException 500 : INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"

here below are the logs of how much tracked is server-side
!ENTRY org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared 4 0 2020-07-14 14:11:46.295
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.services.common.exceptionhandler.LogExceptionHandlerService.differentiatedLog(LogExceptionHandlerService.java:77) ProcessingStatus[ERROR code=0 Identity=admin, Job=loading session ServerSession / SQL with binds:
SELECT    RORUSERID,
ROLEID
FROM      USERROLES
WHERE     USERACCOUNT = :userId
AND PASSWORD = :pwdId
INTO      :personNr,
:roleId
IN  :userId => ? [VARCHAR admin] / Cannot find input for 'ValueInputToken[parsed 'PASSWORD = :pwdId', replaced 'PASSWORD = :pwdId']' in bind bases. ]
Cannot find input for 'ValueInputToken[parsed 'PASSWORD = :pwdId', replaced 'PASSWORD = :pwdId']' in bind bases.
!STACK 0

```
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.internal.exec.StatementProcessor.createInput(StatementProcessor.java:902)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.internal.exec.StatementProcessor.<init>(StatementProcessor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.AbstractSqlService.createStatementProcessor(AbstractSqlService.java:779)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.AbstractSqlService.selectInto(AbstractSqlService.java:721)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.SQL.selectInto(SQL.java:117)
at org.zeiss.mo.scout.MyProject.server.ServerSession.execLoadSession(ServerSession.java:34)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.AbstractServerSession$LocalServerSessionExtension.execLoadSession(AbstractServerSession.java:325)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.extension.ServerSessionChains$ServerSessionLoadSessionChain$1.callMethod(ServerSessionChains.java:31)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.extension.ServerSessionChains$ServerSessionLoadSessionChain$1.callMethod(ServerSessionChains.java:1)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.extension.AbstractExtensionChain.callChain(AbstractExtensionChain.java:121)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.extension.ServerSessionChains$ServerSessionLoadSessionChain.execLoadSession(ServerSessionChains.java:34)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.AbstractServerSession.interceptLoadSession(AbstractServerSession.java:333)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.AbstractServerSession.loadSession(AbstractServerSession.java:251)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.session.ServerSessionRegistryService$1.run(ServerSessionRegistryService.java:73)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJobFactory$1.runTransaction(ServerJobFactory.java:28)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob.runTransactionWrapper(ServerJob.java:223)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob$1.run(ServerJob.java:179)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob$1.run(ServerJob.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob.run(ServerJob.java:174)
at org.eclipse.scout.commons.job.JobEx.runNow(JobEx.java:51)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob.runNow(ServerJob.java:166)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJobFactory.runNow(ServerJobFactory.java:42)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.session.ServerSessionRegistryService.runLoadSessionJob(ServerSessionRegistryService.java:68)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.session.ServerSessionRegistryService.newServerSession(ServerSessionRegistryService.java:52)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServiceTunnelServlet.lookupScoutServerSessionOnHttpSession(ServiceTunnelServlet.java:246)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServiceTunnelServlet.lookupServerSession(ServiceTunnelServlet.java:234)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServiceTunnelServlet.doPost(ServiceTunnelServlet.java:338)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.HttpServletEx.access$0(HttpServletEx.java:1)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.HttpServletEx$1.service(HttpServletEx.java:38)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:44)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.SoapWsseJaasFilter$2.run(SoapWsseJaasFilter.java:198)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.SoapWsseJaasFilter.continueChainWithPrincipal(SoapWsseJaasFilter.java:191)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.SoapWsseJaasFilter.doFilter(SoapWsseJaasFilter.java:135)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:41)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.ServletFilterDelegate.delegateServiceMethod(ServletFilterDelegate.java:60)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.HttpServletEx.service(HttpServletEx.java:35)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl$LegacyServlet.service(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:1232)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:63)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:98)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:372)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

!ENTRY org.eclipse.scout.rt.server 4 0 2020-07-14 14:11:46.297
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServiceTunnelServlet.doPost(ServiceTunnelServlet.java:369) Client=admin@127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1
Cannot find input for 'ValueInputToken[parsed 'PASSWORD = :pwdId', replaced 'PASSWORD = :pwdId']' in bind bases.
!STACK 0

```
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.internal.exec.StatementProcessor.createInput(StatementProcessor.java:902)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.internal.exec.StatementProcessor.<init>(StatementProcessor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.AbstractSqlService.createStatementProcessor(AbstractSqlService.java:779)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.AbstractSqlService.selectInto(AbstractSqlService.java:721)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.jdbc.SQL.selectInto(SQL.java:117)
at org.zeiss.mo.scout.MyProject.server.ServerSession.execLoadSession(ServerSession.java:34)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.AbstractServerSession$LocalServerSessionExtension.execLoadSession(AbstractServerSession.java:325)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.extension.ServerSessionChains$ServerSessionLoadSessionChain$1.callMethod(ServerSessionChains.java:31)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.extension.ServerSessionChains$ServerSessionLoadSessionChain$1.callMethod(ServerSessionChains.java:1)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.extension.AbstractExtensionChain.callChain(AbstractExtensionChain.java:121)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.extension.ServerSessionChains$ServerSessionLoadSessionChain.execLoadSession(ServerSessionChains.java:34)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.AbstractServerSession.interceptLoadSession(AbstractServerSession.java:333)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.AbstractServerSession.loadSession(AbstractServerSession.java:251)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.session.ServerSessionRegistryService$1.run(ServerSessionRegistryService.java:73)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJobFactory$1.runTransaction(ServerJobFactory.java:28)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob.runTransactionWrapper(ServerJob.java:223)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob$1.run(ServerJob.java:179)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob$1.run(ServerJob.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob.run(ServerJob.java:174)
at org.eclipse.scout.commons.job.JobEx.runNow(JobEx.java:51)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJob.runNow(ServerJob.java:166)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServerJobFactory.runNow(ServerJobFactory.java:42)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.session.ServerSessionRegistryService.runLoadSessionJob(ServerSessionRegistryService.java:68)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.session.ServerSessionRegistryService.newServerSession(ServerSessionRegistryService.java:52)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServiceTunnelServlet.lookupScoutServerSessionOnHttpSession(ServiceTunnelServlet.java:246)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServiceTunnelServlet.lookupServerSession(ServiceTunnelServlet.java:234)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.ServiceTunnelServlet.doPost(ServiceTunnelServlet.java:338)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.HttpServletEx.access$0(HttpServletEx.java:1)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.HttpServletEx$1.service(HttpServletEx.java:38)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:44)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.SoapWsseJaasFilter$2.run(SoapWsseJaasFilter.java:198)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.SoapWsseJaasFilter.continueChainWithPrincipal(SoapWsseJaasFilter.java:191)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.SoapWsseJaasFilter.doFilter(SoapWsseJaasFilter.java:135)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:41)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.ServletFilterDelegate.delegateServiceMethod(ServletFilterDelegate.java:60)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.HttpServletEx.service(HttpServletEx.java:35)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl$LegacyServlet.service(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:1232)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:63)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:98)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:372)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and is RAP side
Code: [Select all] [Show/ hide]
!ENTRY org.eclipse.scout.rt.client 4 0 2020-07-14 14:11:46.319
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession.startSession(AbstractClientSession.java:299) load session
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getAllCodeTypeClasses(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.code.CodeServiceClientProxy.getAllCodeTypeClasses(CodeServiceClientProxy.java:351)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.code.CodeServiceClientProxy.getAllCodeTypes(CodeServiceClientProxy.java:372)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.services.common.code.CODES.getAllCodeTypes(CODES.java:97)
at org.zeiss.mo.scout.MyProject.client.ClientSession.execLoadSession(ClientSession.java:34)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession$LocalClientSessionExtension.execLoadSession(AbstractClientSession.java:671)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.extension.ClientSessionChains$ClientSessionLoadSessionChain$1.callMethod(ClientSessionChains.java:52)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.extension.ClientSessionChains$ClientSessionLoadSessionChain$1.callMethod(ClientSessionChains.java:1)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.extension.AbstractExtensionChain.callChain(AbstractExtensionChain.java:121)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.extension.ClientSessionChains$ClientSessionLoadSessionChain.execLoadSession(ClientSessionChains.java:55)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession.interceptLoadSession(AbstractClientSession.java:685)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession.startSession(AbstractClientSession.java:294)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService$1.runVoid(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:64)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.runStatus(ClientJob.java:189)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.runTransactionWrapper(ClientJob.java:172)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.run(ClientJob.java:159)
at org.eclipse.scout.commons.job.JobEx.runNow(JobEx.java:51)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService.createAndStartClientSession(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:68)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService.newClientSession(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:49)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.createNewSession(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:490)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.initClientSession(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:469)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.init(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:374)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.ensureInitialized(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:319)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.createApplicationContent(AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.java:101)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.createContents(AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.java:76)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.application.AbstractEntryPoint.createUI(AbstractEntryPoint.java:59)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.createUI(AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.java:68)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:283)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:104)
Caused by: ProcessingException[ProcessingStatus[ERROR code=0 Calling ICodeService.getAllCodeTypeClasses() org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.servicetunnel.HttpException: 500 - INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR]]
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.servicetunnel.AbstractServiceTunnel.invokeService(AbstractServiceTunnel.java:115)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.servicetunnel.http.internal.AbstractInternalHttpServiceTunnel.invokeService(AbstractInternalHttpServiceTunnel.java:130)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.servicetunnel.http.ClientHttpServiceTunnel.invokeService(ClientHttpServiceTunnel.java:121)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.servicetunnel.ServiceTunnelInvocationHandler.invoke(ServiceTunnelInvocationHandler.java:48)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getAllCodeTypeClasses(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.code.CodeServiceClientProxy.getAllCodeTypeClasses(CodeServiceClientProxy.java:351)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.code.CodeServiceClientProxy.getAllCodeTypes(CodeServiceClientProxy.java:372)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.services.common.code.CODES.getAllCodeTypes(CODES.java:97)
at org.zeiss.mo.scout.MyProject.client.ClientSession.execLoadSession(ClientSession.java:34)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession$LocalClientSessionExtension.execLoadSession(AbstractClientSession.java:671)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.extension.ClientSessionChains$ClientSessionLoadSessionChain$1.callMethod(ClientSessionChains.java:52)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.extension.ClientSessionChains$ClientSessionLoadSessionChain$1.callMethod(ClientSessionChains.java:1)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.extension.AbstractExtensionChain.callChain(AbstractExtensionChain.java:121)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.extension.ClientSessionChains$ClientSessionLoadSessionChain.execLoadSession(ClientSessionChains.java:55)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession.interceptLoadSession(AbstractClientSession.java:685)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.AbstractClientSession.startSession(AbstractClientSession.java:294)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService$1.runVoid(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:64)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.runStatus(ClientJob.java:189)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.runTransactionWrapper(ClientJob.java:172)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.run(ClientJob.java:159)
at org.eclipse.scout.commons.job.JobEx.runNow(JobEx.java:51)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService.createAndStartClientSession(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:68)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.services.common.session.internal.ClientSessionRegistryService.newClientSession(ClientSessionRegistryService.java:49)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.createNewSession(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:490)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.initClientSession(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:469)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.init(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:374)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.ensureInitialized(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:319)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.createApplicationContent(AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.java:101)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.createContents(AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.java:76)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.application.AbstractEntryPoint.createUI(AbstractEntryPoint.java:59)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.createUI(AbstractStandaloneRwtEnvironment.java:68)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:283)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:104)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.servicetunnel.AbstractServiceTunnel.invokeService(AbstractServiceTunnel.java:119)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.servicetunnel.http.internal.AbstractInternalHttpServiceTunnel.invokeService(AbstractInternalHttpServiceTunnel.java:130)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.servicetunnel.http.ClientHttpServiceTunnel.invokeService(ClientHttpServiceTunnel.java:121)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.servicetunnel.ServiceTunnelInvocationHandler.invoke(ServiceTunnelInvocationHandler.java:48)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.servicetunnel.HttpException: 500 - INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.servicetunnel.http.internal.HttpBackgroundExecutable.run(HttpBackgroundExecutable.java:91)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.servicetunnel.http.internal.InternalClientHttpServiceTunnel$2.runStatus(InternalClientHttpServiceTunnel.java:209)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.runTransactionWrapper(ClientJob.java:172)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ClientJob.run(ClientJob.java:159)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap 4 0 2020-07-14 14:11:56.680
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.AbstractRwtEnvironment.init(AbstractRwtEnvironment.java:377) ClientSession is not active, there must be a problem with loading or starting

Here the configuration made
Code: [Select all] [Show/ hide]
org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#active=false
org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#realm=Development
org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#jdbcDriverName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#jdbcMappingName=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxx:0000:xxx
org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#jdbcUsername=xxxxxx
org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#jdbcPassword=xxxxxxx
org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#selectUserPass=SELECT USERACCOUNT FROM USERROLES WHERE LOWER(USERACCOUNT)=? AND PASSWORD=?

I use Oracle 12.1.0.2 JDBC Driver for Eclipse Scout

Someone can help me to fix this error.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The "..Cannot find input for 'ValueInputToken[parsed 'PASSWORD = :pwdId', replaced 'PASSWORD = :pwdId']' in bind bases. ] Cannot find input for 'ValueInputToken[parsed 'PASSWORD = :pwdId', replaced 'PASSWORD = :pwdId']' in bind bases. !STACK 0.." part of the logs is your hint. Make sure that the ":pwdId" in your SQL statement has a getter() & setter() in your form, e.g. getPwdId() & setPwdId(..)..  If it does make sure those methods are reflected on formData model.